# Running a script in IPython with input from a file

Tags: python, input, ipython

I have a python script, which for the purpose of this question can be reduced to:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
# do something with data ...
```

The idea is to run this script from the shell as

```
python my_script.py < datafile
```

Now I'd like to call the script from IPython using the `run` command and tried the following:

```
In [1]: run my_script.py < datafile
```

But apparently this doesn't read from `datafile`, and still waits for user input on the IPython terminal.

How can I have the `run` command read standard input from a file instead of from the terminal? I checked the documentation of the `run` command, but this doesn`t contain any pointers.

I'm specifically looking for answers where I can access variables that are defined in the script (`data` in the example here) from the IPython terminal after having called the script.

Comment: What is this run command? And why do you need to use it?

Comment: @Paco I hope my edit clarifies the question why I am using the run command in IPython.

Comment: %run doesn't provide a way to modify stdin. You could build a wrapper for it that sets stdin, runs the script, and sets stdin back to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try?

```
data = !cat datafile
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, so something like `out = !python my_script.py < datafile` will at least capture the scripts output in a variable to inspect. But not variables defined in the script unfortunately.

Comment: if the sole purpose of the script is to get the file content into a var, then you do not need the scriot, just replace it with data=!cat datafile. Now data is populated in the main script and you can do whatever munging you may planned in script.

Comment: Loading the file contents is not the sole purpose. The script does more computations with data, and I want to inspect the results of the script in IPython. I have edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to execute the script this way:

```
In [1]: !python my_script.py < datafile
```

Obviously, this works around the `run` command, but it allows you to execute your script from within IPython.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem I get here is that I can't access variables defined in the script (e.g. `data` in the example) from the IPython terminal afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to write this in a little different manner. For example, the following code might do what you want:

```
import sys
data = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
```

Then from the IPython terminal, you use `%run` without the `<` symbol.

```
In [1]: %run my_script.py my_data.txt
```